# Why does string holding an IP require 15 byte when the size is only 4?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

As per my understanding, a `char` in C++ requires 1 byte. So a string holding an IP address should have a size of 15 bytes. Consider this code:

```
char *temp = new char[15];
ifstream iss("file.txt"); //contains an ip address
iss >> temp;

cout << "temp : "<< temp << " ";
cout << sizeof (temp) << endl;
```

It displays size as 4. Can someone please explain why? 
I then tried the same except that I allocated only 4 bytes to `temp` this time:

```
    char *temp = new char[4];
```

This time result was previous result appended with :

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/HelloWorld: double free or corruption (out): 0x08557030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb758bee2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x154)[0xb757b424]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt12__basic_fileIcE5closeEv+0x47)[0xb7746b87]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv+0x98)[0xb7784328]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev+0x3f)[0xb77846af]
/home/HelloWorld[0x8048e2d]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb752f4d3]
/home/HelloWorld[0x8048ab1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 536973     /home/HelloWorld
0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 536973     /home/HelloWorld
0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 536973     /home/HelloWorld
08557000-08578000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b74e8000-b74ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74ea000-b7514000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655846     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
b7514000-b7515000 r--p 00029000 08:01 655846     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
b7515000-b7516000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 655846     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
b7516000-b76ba000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655851     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b76ba000-b76bc000 r--p 001a4000 08:01 655851     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b76bc000-b76bd000 rw-p 001a6000 08:01 655851     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b76bd000-b76c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76c1000-b76dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655821     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b76dc000-b76dd000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 655821     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b76dd000-b76de000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 655821     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b76de000-b77bb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 792998     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
b77bb000-b77bf000 r--p 000dc000 08:01 792998     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
b77bf000-b77c0000 rw-p 000e0000 08:01 792998     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
b77c0000-b77c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77d5000-b77d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77d9000-b77da000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77da000-b77fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 655841     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77fa000-b77fb000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 655841     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77fb000-b77fc000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 655841     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bff69000-bff8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Which I'm guessing is because of insufficient memory allocation. Can someone please explain how is memory being managed here?

Comment: `sizeof(temp)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char*)` here.

Comment: to be completely safe, shouldn't it be `new char[16]; char[15] = '\0'`, for the `'\0'` ?

Comment: It would be even safer to use std::string. Also if you use new you should make sure that the memory gets `delete`d after you're done with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` has type of `char *`, so `sizeof (temp)` gets the size of a pointer, which is usually the same as the word size of your machine, i.e, 4 bytes for 32-bit machine and 8 bytes for 64-bit machine.

To get the length of a C-style string, use `std::strlen(temp)` from `<cstring>`

Comment: strlen isn't part of std: it should be just ::strlen.

Comment: @cup: It is if you include `<cstring>`, rather than `<string.h>`.

Comment: In some implementations, there is `::strlen` too if you include `<cstring>`, but it's not guaranteed. In C++ code, use `std::strlen` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Hmm - must be something new that I missed.  I wonder which implementations ::strlen doesn't work on.  Seems to be OK on windows, AIX, Solaris, HPUX and Linux.  Anyway, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

By using `sizeof(temp)`, you end up with the size of a pointer, which is 4 bytes on a 32 bit system.

And the corruption occurs because you allocated 4 bytes for your char array on the heap, and then attempted to fill it with 15 bytes of data from a file, causing a corruption.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as writing any number - to write 221 you need 3 characters, because of the decimal system we are using. However, you can write 221 in binary and put it in exactly one byte: binary `11011101`, hex `DD`. Depending on what kind of system you are using, a representation of a number differs in length. In general, the more possibilities (2 vs 10 vs 16) per character, the shorter the string.

You may say that writing numbers as strings is inefficient. Each bit used to do that is not used to its fullest. Google `Information Theory`, and everything will be exaplained.

And a more interesting example: usually people count on their fingers to 10 - because they have 10 fingers. But using binary code you can count up to 1023 on your fingers!

Comment: That's interesting and all, but why did you decide to write it here?  Do you have another question open in another tab which this is the answer to, but you put it here by mistake?  Because it certainly has nothing to do with the question in this post.  By the way, you can count up to 59048 on your fingers if you use trinary, a crooked finger being a 1, and an extended finger being a 2.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the basic programming problem has been solved in other answers. And my post directly answers the question's topic `Why does string holding an IP require 15 byte when the size is only 4?.

Comment: The reason that the size is four is because is gettin the size of the pointer and not of the allocated array (that cannot be got in any way in both in C or C++). Incidentally, 4 is also the size of 4 bytes (what an IPV4 address is) and being textually writen as dot separated number between 0 ans 255 requires 4*3+3=12 characters. That's why you misunderstood the question, that is made by its all text, and not just the title.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia yeah, but consider this: people googling for the topic will actually have what question?